# Python: How to dynamically create parameterized anonomous/lambda functions?

Tags: python, lambda

I need to create a function that parameterizes another function whereby some parameters are explicitly set and others are only set during the call to that function. (I have tried to make the question as succinct as possible whilst conveying the general specification of my problem) this is a brief implementation of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
class registration():
   #...
   def register(self, func, **kwargs):
     # ... append spec to internal dict

class spec():
     def __init__(self, func, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = **kwargs

     def __call__(self, *args):
        # should call func with the 

reg = registration()
def register(func, **kwargs)
    reg.register(func, **kwargs)

def func (**kwargs):
    for i in range(kwargs['param2'])
        print(kwargs[])
        print(kwargs['param3']['something'])

def func2 (**kwargs):
    if kwargs['param3']:
       print(kwargs['param1'])
    else:
       print(kwargs['param2'])


 register(func, param1 = "answer:", param2 = lambda x: x ** 0, param3 = {"something": lambda x: x * 8})

 # spec[0](111,8) -> answer: 1 64

 register(func2, param1= "hello", param2 = "goodbye", param3= x: if x >=0: return True; else: return False; ) 

 # spec[1](1) -> hello
```

My problem is how to effectively implement the functionality with regards to mapping/inputting the args in the call to the spec class and the parameters as shown above regardless of their position in the register function. This is especially significant when multiple registrations are implemented as shown above.

How could I most effectively implement the process of passing the parameters as in functools.partial, but for multiple different arrangements?

Comment: Can you please clarify the example? I see that you pass lambdas to the `register()` call, but mention `param2=111` in the text. Also, what is the relation between `spec` & `registration`? Why would `spec()` be 64, and not the instance of the class?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Please explain what you are actually trying to achieve here. I do not believe think what you think you need to do there is really something you should even consider doing.

Comment: Also, isn't it solved by the stdlib's `functools.partial` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)?

Comment: The poor formatting of the contents of your question make it virtually impossible to comprehend.